# SQL Server login username and password

Tags: sql-server, authentication

My SQL Server use Windows authentication for logging in. I was wondering how I can give the right username password for this db in the connection string.

Comment: `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - `Integrated Security=SSPI;` is another syntax variant.

Comment: @Oded Yeah, I use the SSPI syntax at work, but I think Trusted_Connection is more self-explanatory.

Comment: thanks, the problem is I want to connect it with a jdbc and the syntax should be like:

Comment: type="JdbcDataSource" name="ds-1"
     driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
     url="jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1;databaseName=AdventureWorks" 
     user="sa"
     password="password"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using IWA no username or password should be required, the credentials used are the ones from the user executing the program and this is transparent to your program.

Your connection string has to specify that you intend to use IWA.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx#Connectingintegrated